# Interfaces, Inheritance and the 'new' keyword

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I am wondering if someone can please explain this to me:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        AnotherDerivedClass d = new AnotherDerivedClass();
        Console.WriteLine(d.PrintMessage());

        IMsg m = d as IMsg;
        //Why this prints BaseClass.
        //How does it know that IMsg is implemented in the BaseClass.
        Console.WriteLine(m.PrintMessage());

        IMsg n = d as DerivedClass;
        //Why this prints BaseClass and not DerivedClass
        Console.WriteLine(n.PrintMessage());

        Console.Read();
    }
}

public interface IMsg
{
    string PrintMessage();
}

public class BaseClass : IMsg
{
    public string PrintMessage()
    {
        return "BaseClass";
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new string PrintMessage()
    {
        return "DerivedClass";
    }
}

public class AnotherDerivedClass : DerivedClass
{
    public new string PrintMessage()
    {
        return "AnotherDerivedClass";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question you have? ... Ah, I see you have questions as comments in your code :)

Comment: It is much better to ask the questions in the question body, not in code comments as people gloss over code listings looking for the question...

Comment: I thought it will be easy for people to understand what i want to understand if i ask question in the code comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have replaced the implementation in your derived classes, not overridden them. If you use the `BaseClass`, the original implementation will be used.

You need to make the method in the base virtual:

```
public class BaseClass : IMsg
{

    public BaseClass()
    {

    }

    public virtual string PrintMessage()
    {
        return "BaseClass";
    }
}
```

and override in the derived class:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass()
    {

    }

    public override string PrintMessage()
    {
        return "DerivedClass";
    }
}
```

to get the behaviour you specified.

Comment: What i understand is "New" keyword will hide the baseclass implementation. So if the baseclass implementation is hidden, isnt it suppose to call New implementation?

Comment: @Asdfg, that's not how it works. Use `new` when the base method does not do what you want and it is not `virtual` and cannot be overriden. However, this only *hides* the base implementation as long as you are operating with through a reference to the derived type. References to the object *via* the base class will continue to use the base behavior. That is why it is absolutely preferrable to use the `virtual` modifier on base methods you truly intend to override in derived classes.